# handling multiple tasks/jobs on a resource constrained system

Tags: python, architecture, scripting, software-design

First of all, thanks for taking time to answer this.

I have a design question (sort of). I have a set of machines against which users can perform tasks. Each task may take about 5-20 minutes to finish on the machine. Any number of users can perform tasks - however, they may not care if their tasks are queued and are not performed instantly.

As a software developer, I would like to limit the number of tasks that I execute to 10 per batch to prevent crashing the end system. This was what I was thinking would be my way to do it:

```
a) Submit all jobs/tasks to a file.
b) Daemon wakes up every x minutes, checks if there is work to be performed.
b) Get 10 jobs that were submitted earliest and spawn processes to handle the tasks.
c) Daemon sleeps, wakes up again after x minutes and checks how many additional tasks can be performed (given that some of the 10 tasks may still be running), launches the corresponding tasks and goes back to sleep.
```

Any suggestions or ideas from you guys?

Comment: How important is it that you don't lose tasks in the queue if the computer does crash or lose power unexpectedly?

Comment: Would be important, hence the file

Comment: Any thoughts on how to handle the ones that are currently "in flight"?

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you investigate [Message Queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue).  Using a message queue to store your jobs will allow your system to scale, and will handle things like transactionality, persistence, throttling, etc. Otherwise you will have to write your own handling of things like file locks, transactional rollbacks, etc.

This approach will also let you scale out, allowing many machines to subscribe to a single queue.

There are lots of free/open source message queue servers out there, [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) is one of the more popular ones, and you should be able to get up and running on it fairly quickly.